# Issue loading MDX Query into PowerBI when it loads into SSMS with no problems

Tags: powerbi, ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a dashboard in PowerBI that refreshes with the information in a Pivot Table by connecting directly to a SSAS Cube. I retrieved the MDX query from the Excel file and the query runs perfectly in SSMS. However, when I import the query to PowerBI, the numerical data loads in, but the categorization data (text) loads in as [Plant].[Plant].[All] rather than the actual Plant name. Any insight into why this is happening?

```
SELECT 
  CrossJoin(
    {[Measures].[Closing Balance Amount], 
    [Measures].[Closing Balance Quantity]}, 
    Hierarchize(
      {DrilldownLevel(
        {[Product SKU - Material].[Material Type].[All]}
      ) }
    )
  ) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, 
  HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY CrossJoin(
    CrossJoin(
      CrossJoin(
        Hierarchize(
          {DrilldownLevel(
            {[Profit Center].[Profit Center].[All]}
          ) }
        ), 
        Hierarchize(
          {DrilldownLevel(
            {[Product Hierarchy].[L11 BFPP].[All]}
          ) }
        )
      ), 
      Hierarchize(
        {DrilldownLevel(
          {[Product Hierarchy].[L14 SKU].[All]}
        ) }
      )
    ), 
    Hierarchize(
      {DrilldownLevel({[Plant].[Plant].[All]}) }
    )
  ) DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, 
  HIERARCHY_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      (
        {[Product SKU - Material].[Material Type].& [1U] & [ROH], 
        [Product SKU - Material].[Material Type].& [1U] & [PACK], 
        [Product SKU - Material].[Material Type].& [1U] & [HALB], 
        [Product SKU - Material].[Material Type].& [1U] & [FERT]}
      ) ON COLUMNS, 
      (
        {[Profit Center].[Profit Center].& [1U] & [ULAM] & [0000100058], 
        [Profit Center].[Profit Center].& [1U] & [ULAM] & [0000100075], 
        [Profit Center].[Profit Center].& [1U] & [ULAM] & [0000100022], 
        [Profit Center].[Profit Center].& [1U] & [ULAM] & [0000100090], 
        [Profit Center].[Profit Center].& [1U] & [ULAM] & [0000100091], 
        [Profit Center].[Profit Center].& [1U] & [ULAM] & [0000900015]}
      ) ON ROWS 
    FROM 
      [Stock Balance]
  ) 
WHERE 
  (
    [Reporting Currency].[Reporting Currency].& [USD], 
    [Segment].[Segment].& [1U] & [0000001010], 
    [Company Code].[Company].[All], 
    [Time].[Month].& [2019] & [4]
  ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, 
  FORMAT_STRING, 
  LANGUAGE, 
  BACK_COLOR, 
  FORE_COLOR, 
  FONT_FLAGS
```

I would like to see the Plant name and SKU names rather than just the references.

Comment: Hi Emily, please can you add the MDX to the question

Comment: Do you only get this behaviour with [Plant] or does it also happen with the other hierarchies?

Comment: It happens with all the hierarchies

Comment: hmmm ... I added an 'answer' but sorry it is not much of a help. We have very mature OLAP cubes but we are currently porting over to Tabular so we can get the most out of Power BI ...

Answer (score 1):

I have the following against Adventure Works:

1.

```
SELECT
   [Measures].[Internet Order Count] on 0,
   [Customer].[Customer].[Customer] on 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Then I import this into Power BI via "Import" and the above `MDX` script.

The only slight oddity in Power BI is that the column headers/names are the full addresses:

[image]

This is trivial to change though - very easy to adjust the column headers.

In the table the member names look fine:

[image]

2.

If I include the `ALL` member then things get strange.
So the script I use is now this:

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[Internet Order Count] on 0,
   {
    [Customer].[Customer].[All Customers],
    [Customer].[Customer].[Customer]
   } on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

All Customers does not now appear in the visualization - definitely not good:

[image]

3.

So last I tried a *live connection* - now there is no ALL member at all, in the fields area, but at least the column headers are clean:

[image]

---

So I'd suggest either using a live connection to your cube OR start exploring Tabular cubes and get a plan to move over to Tabular as that is the flavour of SSAS which Power BI likes best.